# Issues installing and running pivpn (loop because it doesn't like my kernel?) wireguard

Tags: pi-4, vpn, berryboot

I have a raspberry pi 4b with 32gb sd card and attached to a SSD (usb3 port). Berryboot loads raspbain on ssd to run. This works fine

I tried simply just running curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash
It wants me to update my kernel before wireguard will even install I think. It is a loop asking me to reboot and update a kernel that is already the lastest even when it says it's not.
I literally don't know what is going wrong.

I figure this is because the newest kernel for raspbian OS doesn't work for wireguard or that it won't work on a raspbian desktop... but it said it could on the pivpn webpage.

Comment: I've installed wireguard on 4.19.97 - what version are you running

Comment: run `apt-cache policy raspberrypi-kernel` ... if the installed and candidate are the same, then you have the latest kernel - otherwise, you don't

Comment: I think it is the berryboot kernel that is messing everything up. My raspbian os kernel is the 4.19.75 last I checked.